# Casting collections in WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I am looping through my XML file to capture a list of deposits and pass them to my Business Logic Layer as a list. I'm getting an error on my return statement that says that anonymous type collection does not contain a definition for `to.list`.  If I leave the `to.list` off the return statement I get an error on the `select` saying that I'm missing a cast as it can't covert the anonymous collection to a list. How can I resolve this?

**DATA ACCESS LAYER**

```
public class DepositList
{
    public string Depid { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }
    public string DepDate { get; set; }
}

public class DLDeposits
{
    public List<DepositList> getDeposits(string customerid)
    {

        double sumDep = 0;
        //Returns list of deposits for selected customer
        var doc = XDocument.Load("Portfolio.xml");

        List<DepositList> result = from account in doc.Descendants("account")
                       from deposit in account.Elements("deposits")
                       where (string)account.Element("acct").Attribute("custid").Value == customerid
                       select new
                       {
                           Depid = (string)deposit.Attribute("depid").Value,
                           Amount = (string)deposit.Attribute("depamount").Value,
                           DepDate = (string)deposit.Attribute("depdate").Value
                       }.ToList();

        return result;
    }
}
```

**BUSINESS LOGIC LAYER**

```
    public double  getDeposits(string customerId)
    {
        double sumDep = 0;
        //Returns list of deposits for selected customer
        var doc = XDocument.Load("Portfolio.xml");
        CustCount(doc);

        DLDeposits obj = new DLDeposits();
        var depositList = obj.getDeposits(customerId);

                        for (int i = 0; i < NumCusts; i++)
                        {
                            BL_Deposit oDeposit = new BL_Deposit();
                            oDeposit.DepAmt = Convert.ToDouble(depositList[i].Amount);
                            oDeposit.DepDate = Convert.ToDateTime(depositList[i].DepDate);
                            oDeposit.DepositId = Convert.ToInt32(depositList[i].Depid);
                            addDeposits(oDeposit);
                            sumDep += oDeposit.DepAmt;
                        }
                        return sumDep;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating a new list of an anonymous type, not a `List<DepositList>`. You just need to change your `select` clause to:

```
select new DepositList
{
    Depid = (string) deposit.Attribute("depid"),
    Amount = (string) deposit.Attribute("depamount"),
    DepDate = (string) deposit.Attribute("depdate")
}
```

Note that I've removed the use of the `Value` property - you didn't need both that *and* the cast to string, and by using the explicit conversion from `XAttribute` to `string`, you'll end up with `null` instead of a `NullReferenceException` if the attribute is missing.

However, it strikes me that it would be better if `DepositList` were rather more strongly typed, like this:

```
public class DepositList
{
    public int Depid { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public DateTime DepDate { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could use:

```
select new DepositList
{
    Depid = (int) deposit.Attribute("depid"),
    Amount = (decimal) deposit.Attribute("depamount"),
    DepDate = (DateTime) deposit.Attribute("depdate")
}
```

and LINQ to XML will do the conversion for you. (In this case it *will* throw an exception if any attribute is missing, as I'm using non-nullable value types.)

Note that I've made `Amount` a `decimal` instead of a `double`. You should *not* be using `double` for financial values.